# django ListView Нужна Помощь

Tags: django, listview

Я хочу не так -

```
url(r'^$',ListView.as_view(queryset=News.objects.all().order_by("dateNews")[:20],template_name="index.html"))
```

А типо так-

```
url(r'^$',ListView.as_view(queryset=News.objects.all().order_by("dateNews")[:20]),views.index)
```

Но это вызывает ошибку. Что делать? Как написать?

index/models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class News(models.Model):
    titleNews = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    textNews = models.TextField()
    dateNews = models.DateTimeField()
```

index/admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from index.models import News

admin.site.register(News)
```

index/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request,'index.html',{'Title':'Главная','year':now.year})
```

index/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.views.generic import ListView,DetailView
from index.models import News
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',ListView.as_view(queryset=News.objects.all().order_by("dateNews")[:20],template_name="index.html"))
]
```

Comment: одному url должно соответствовать одно представление.

Comment: просто во index/views.py у меня передается переменные а я их теперь не могу передать

Comment: переопределите View класс, метод get_context_data

Answer (score 0):

Вы не можете сделать так, как хотите

> url(r'^$',ListView.as_view(queryset=News.objects.all().order_by("dateNews")[:20]),views.index

Вы тут пытаетесь передать 2 view в разных параметрах. Напишите, что конкретно хотите решить

---

Если вам надо указать параметры для контекста view, то переопределите метод `get_context_data`

```
...
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ctx = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        ctx['title'] = 'The main page forever!!!'
        return ctx
```